# mock geolocation with nightmarejs

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, electron, nightmare

i have tried this

```
window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(callback) {
                var position = {
                    coords : {
                        latitude : '55.755826',
                        longitude : '37.6173'
                    }
                };
                callback(position);
            };
```

but nothing happened, looks google still use my IP address location, not the position i mocked.
please help me, thanks

full code:

```
nightmare
    .useragent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36")
    .goto("https://www.google.com")
    .wait('input[name=q]')
    .type('form[action*="/search"] [name=q]', false) // clean input text
    .type('form[action*="/search"] [name=q]', "hotels")
    .click('form[action*="/search"] [type=submit]')
    .wait('#center_col')
    .evaluate(function() {
        console.log(1);
        window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(callback) {
            var position = {
                coords : {
                    latitude : '55.755826',
                    longitude : '37.6173'
                }
            };
            callback(position);
        };
    })
```

Comment: When does the browser check for the user location? I guess you're injecting your script after the browser has called `window.navigator.geo...` Try to inject the script after the `goto` line

Comment: @kontrollanten found the solution, use nightmarejs preload to solve this issue, this make sure the location was mocked before google check user location